# Flashvars or like in Captivate 8?

Tags: adobe-captivate

I'm looking to pass from an HTML page, a "StudentName", and "StudentEmail" and populate the Captivate 8 TextBox fields with this name. I've attached a screenshot of how Captivate currently looks. Essentially, I want to is pre-populate the two text fields with the values passed from an HTML page.

How do I accomplish this in Captivate 8? I know in Flash, you could use Flashvars as this article shows: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html#main_Use_FlashVars_to_pass_values_to_a_SWF_file.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can pass these two values into a CPTX file?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all of the Common JS Interface commands work with both SWF and HTML5 output, you'll want

`window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue("StudentName","John");`

https://helpx.adobe.com/captivate/using/common-js-interface.html